# how to call linux so library's certain export function?

Tags: export, shared-libraries

The so library has several export functions. Let's say one of them is test(). I could see test() in this so's export functions list. Now I'd like to only call the test() function in command line. How should I get it?

Comment: Unless you write a program that will take a library name, function name and it's parameter list/types from command line - you can't.

Comment: is there a existed program in Linux, just like rundll32.exe in Windows?

Comment: None of i've heard of. And it doesn't make much sense - C functions are rarely using only builtin types and often require some initialisation. You can, however, take a look at e.g. python's ctypes (http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can find, is Perl. You can use [PDL::CallExt](http://pdl.perl.org/PDLdocs/CallExt.html)

`callext()` loads in an **so** using Perl's dynamic loader, calls the named function and passes a list of [piddle](http://pdl.perl.org/PDLdocs/PP.html) arguments to it.

You can even use Perl to compile C into a shared object with appropriate flags, so you can create native library on the fly.